# Assertion failure sdl2 android

Tags: c++, opengl, opengles, sdl2

Написал заготовку для игры для android на sdl2 и opengl opengl es. При запуске на android пишет такую ошибку.

```
Assertion failure at
SDL_GL_CreateContext_REAL_(/home/xverizex/projects/SDL2-2.0.9/build/com.xverizex.hack/app/jni/SDL/src/video/SDL_video.c:3471), triggered 1 time:
'window && window->magic == &_this->window_magic'
```

Хотя код стандартный. Вот.

```
#include "game.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "global.hpp"

Game::Game ( )
{
    SDL_Init ( SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_EVENTS );
    SDL_DisplayMode mode;
    SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode ( 0, &mode );
    width = mode.w;
    height = mode.h;

#if 0
    width = 1024;
    height = 600;
#endif

    global.width = width;
    global.height = height;

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0 );

    window = SDL_CreateWindow ( "hackingtoday",
                                0, 0,
                                width, height,
                                SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN );

    SDL_GLContext glc;

    glc = SDL_GL_CreateContext ( window );
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent ( window, glc );

    const GLubyte *version = glGetString ( GL_VERSION );
    if ( version == 0 ) {
        printf ( "%d\n", glGetError() );
    }
    if ( version )
        printf ( "%s\n", version );

    glViewport ( 0, 0, width, height );
    glMatrixMode ( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity ( );

#if 0
    glOrtho ( 0.0f, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0f, 1.0f );
#endif
    glMatrixMode ( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity ( );
    glEnable ( GL_BLEND );
    glBlendFunc ( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
}

void Game::loop ( )
{
    ShaderManager *sm = new ShaderManager ( );
    sm->createProgram ( "sprite" );
    Sprite *sprite = new Sprite ( );
    sprite->load ( 0 );
    sprite->setPos ( 100, 100 );
    sprite->setSize ( 256, 256 );
    glClearColor ( 1, 1, 1, 1 );
    while ( 1 ) {
        SDL_Event event;
        SDL_PollEvent ( &event );

        const Uint8 *state = SDL_GetKeyboardState ( NULL );
        if ( state [ SDL_SCANCODE_Q ] ) {
            SDL_Quit ( );
            std::exit ( EXIT_SUCCESS );
        }
        glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    sprite->draw ( );

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow ( window );
        SDL_Delay ( 1 );

    }
}
```

Comment: Поменял SDL_GL_MAJOR_VERSION на 2, и вообще перестало запускаться.

Comment: Чтобы был GL ES, надо его через `SDL_GL_SetAttribute` запросить.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat вот это         SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_ES );

Comment: Да, вроде бы так.